# Upload image from iPhone to server using WCF service using SOAP

Tags: ios, xcode, wcf, soap, image-uploading

hiii, i'm using wcf SOAP services for my app and i send the request like below.

```
postStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
           "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
           "<s:Body>\n"
           "<InsUpdDelActivityInfo xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
           "<objEventsContent xmlns:d4p1=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/iCampuslite.Model.ActivityStream\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n"
           "<d4p1:ActCommentId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:ActSubTypeCd i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:ActType>Status</d4p1:ActType>\n"
           "<d4p1:ActTypeCd>1</d4p1:ActTypeCd>\n"
           "<d4p1:ActivityAnswersList />\n"
           "<d4p1:ActivityComments />\n"
           "<d4p1:ActivityId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:ActivityLike />\n"
           "<d4p1:ActivityName>%@</d4p1:ActivityName>\n"
           "<d4p1:ActivityStreamImagesBytes>%@</d4p1:ActivityStreamImagesBytes>\n"
           "<d4p1:AnswerDesc i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:AnswerId>0</d4p1:AnswerId>\n"
           "<d4p1:CommentDesc i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:CommentId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:CreatedUserId>%@</d4p1:CreatedUserId>\n"
           "<d4p1:CreatedUserName i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:FileOrLinkName i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:IsLiked>0</d4p1:IsLiked>\n"
           "<d4p1:IsTotalSchool i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:LikeCount>0</d4p1:LikeCount>\n"
           "<d4p1:LinkImage i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:ObjTypeCdId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:ObjTypeId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:OperationMode>I</d4p1:OperationMode>\n"
           "<d4p1:OperationType i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:OperationTypeId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "<d4p1:OrganizationId>%@</d4p1:OrganizationId>\n"
           "<d4p1:OtherActivityId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
           "%@\n"
           "</objEventsContent>\n"
           "<ismobile>true</ismobile>\n"
           "</InsUpdDelActivityInfo>\n"
           "</s:Body>\n"
           "</s:Envelope>", statusText, [appDelegateObj.loginUserInfoDict valueForKey:@"a:UserId"], [appDelegateObj.loginUserInfoDict valueForKey:@"a:OrgId"], workspaceStr];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@iCampusliteMobileService/ActivityStreamSl.svc", appDelegateObj.baseURL]]];
NSString *messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postStr length]];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/IActivityStreamSl/InsUpdDelActivityInfo" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[request addValue:messageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
```

in the above request there is an element `ActivityStreamImagesBytes` which is `base64binary` parameter i have to pass the image.

I've tried using many different formats.

here is wcf service screenshot [image: here]

and here is the server side code

```
public string byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn,string fileName)
    {
        if (byteArrayIn != null)
        {
            ActivityStreamSl.LogMsg("Byte Array Count : "+byteArrayIn.Length.ToString(), "D:\\log.txt");
            var serverfile = "D:somepath\somepath\somefolder";
            var getfile = HelperClass.Filesavehelper(Constants.UploadPaths.ActivityStream, "testfilename.png", serverfile);

            FileStream file = new FileStream(getfile, FileMode.Create);
            file.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
            file.Close();
            file.Dispose();
            return getfile;
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityStreamSl.LogMsg("Byte array is null","D:\\log.txt");
        }
        return "";
    }
```

the server is expecting a byte array and i dont know how to send it?
And i dont know what a base64binary data type is?
Do I have to send the base64 encoded string or byte array or just data of image from `NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"popular.png"], 0.7);`

Any help is appreciable

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893/how-do-you-embed-binary-data-in-xml According to it you need to encode you binary data using Base64 and then add an attribute dt:dt="binary.base64 to the node. BTW, in this case to get image data you can just use [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiii, 
I've got what my problem is

On server side, its expecting a byte array,

So, I've to send my request as follows.

Converting the base64 string into byte array

```
postStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
       "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
       "<s:Body>\n"
       "<InsUpdDelActivityInfo xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
       "<objEventsContent xmlns:d4p1=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/iCampuslite.Model.ActivityStream\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n"
       "<d4p1:ActCommentId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:ActSubTypeCd i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:ActType>Status</d4p1:ActType>\n"
       "<d4p1:ActTypeCd>1</d4p1:ActTypeCd>\n"
       "<d4p1:ActivityAnswersList />\n"
       "<d4p1:ActivityComments />\n"
       "<d4p1:ActivityId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:ActivityLike />\n"
       "<d4p1:ActivityName>%@</d4p1:ActivityName>\n"
       "<d4p1:ActivityStreamImagesBytes dt: dt:"Base64Binary"><dt:length>%d</dt:length><dt:byte>%@</dt:byte>......................................</d4p1:ActivityStreamImagesBytes>\n"
       "<d4p1:AnswerDesc i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:AnswerId>0</d4p1:AnswerId>\n"
       "<d4p1:CommentDesc i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:CommentId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:CreatedUserId>%@</d4p1:CreatedUserId>\n"
       "<d4p1:CreatedUserName i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:FileOrLinkName i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:IsLiked>0</d4p1:IsLiked>\n"
       "<d4p1:IsTotalSchool i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:LikeCount>0</d4p1:LikeCount>\n"
       "<d4p1:LinkImage i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:ObjTypeCdId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:ObjTypeId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:OperationMode>I</d4p1:OperationMode>\n"
       "<d4p1:OperationType i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:OperationTypeId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "<d4p1:OrganizationId>%@</d4p1:OrganizationId>\n"
       "<d4p1:OtherActivityId i:nil=\"true\" />\n"
       "%@\n"
       "</objEventsContent>\n"
       "<ismobile>true</ismobile>\n"
       "</InsUpdDelActivityInfo>\n"
       "</s:Body>\n"
       "</s:Envelope>", statusText, [byteArray length], byteArray[0], byteArray[1], .................................., [appDelegateObj.loginUserInfoDict valueForKey:@"a:UserId"], [appDelegateObj.loginUserInfoDict valueForKey:@"a:OrgId"], workspaceStr];
```

`NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@blah....blah....blah....", appDelegateObj.baseURL]]];`
`NSString *messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postStr length]];`
`[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`
`[request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/blah......blah.....blah............" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];`
`[request addValue:messageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];`
`[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];`
`[request setHTTPBody:[postStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`
`NSError *error = nil;`
`NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];`

I've hosted the services and there i've seen the xml format of the request. Any way thank you @Duraiamuthan.H

Answer (score 2):

The WCF service clearly asks for *base64binary* so you have to send it in base64binary only.

*base64binary* is nothing but *[base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded binary data*.

1) Convert the image to binary using the following code snippet

```
NSData *binaryImageData  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Photo.png"], 0.0);
```

2) Encode the binary into base64 format

Here is the class that I use to handle base64 binary and UIImage

```
 @interface base64BinaryandImagehandler:NSObject
   +(NSString *) base64BinaryStringFromBinaryData: (NSData *)data length: (int)length;
   +(UIImage*)Base64BinaryToImage:(NSString *)Base64;
 @end


 @implementation base64BinaryandImagehandler:NSObject
      static char base64EncodingTable[64] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
    'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
    'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'
     };

 +(NSString *) base64BinaryStringFromBinaryData: (NSData *)data length: (int)length{          

 unsigned long ixtext, lentext;

    long ctremaining;

    unsigned char input[3], output[4];

    short i, charsonline = 0, ctcopy;

    const unsigned char *raw;

    NSMutableString *result;

    lentext = [data length];

    if (lentext < 1)
        return @"";

    result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: lentext];

    raw = [data bytes];

    ixtext = 0;

    while (true) {

        ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;

        if (ctremaining <= 0)
            break;

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            unsigned long ix = ixtext + i;
            if (ix < lentext)
                input[i] = raw[ix];
            else
                input[i] = 0;
        }

        output[0] = (input[0] & 0xFC) >> 2;

        output[1] = ((input[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((input[1] & 0xF0) >> 4);

        output[2] = ((input[1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((input[2] & 0xC0) >> 6);

        output[3] = input[2] & 0x3F;

        ctcopy = 4;

        switch (ctremaining) {
            case 1:
                ctcopy = 2;
                break;

            case 2:
                ctcopy = 3;
                break;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++)
            [result appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", base64EncodingTable[output[i]]]];

        for (i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++)
            [result appendString: @"="];

        ixtext += 3;

        charsonline += 4;

        if ((length > 0) && (charsonline >= length))
            charsonline = 0;
    }
    return result;
      }

  +(UIImage*)Base64BinaryToImage:(NSString *)Base64{      


        NSString* base64String=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@",Base64];

       NSURL *base64url = [NSURL URLWithString:base64String];

       NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:base64url];

       UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

      return img;
     }
 @end
```

Here is the way to convert binary into base64binary

```
NSString *Base64Binary=[base64BinaryandImagehandler base64BinaryStringFromBinaryData:binaryImageData length:binaryImageData.length];
```

You can find more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17571101/730807) as well

Here is the base64 encoding and decoding part in C#

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}

public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Anyhow you can ignore about the C# part since you are doing iPhone part only.

You can use the below link to test if your encoded base 64 is proper.

[base64toimage converter](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/)

**Update 1**
Here is the code that will confirm if the received string is in base64 format or not

```
   private bool IsBase64String(string str){
    try{
    // If not exception is caught, then it is a base64 string
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
    return true;
    }
    catch{
    // If exception is caught, then I assumed it is a normal string
    return false;
    }
    }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29206627/730807)

The below code will create a image under *Images* folder for the given arriving *base64 data* and *filename* of your choice *for example duraiamuthan.jpg* and return the path of the image so that you can update it in the DB
(It will check if the arriving the data is in base64 or binary[just in case WCF framework converts the base64 to binary internally])

```
  public string Getpath_CreateImageFromEncodedData(string Base64EncodedData, string fileName)
        {
        string fileHandle = "";
        try
        {
            if(IsBase64String(Base64EncodedData))
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64EncodedData);
            else
            byte[] imageBytes= Base64EncodedData;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

            fileHandle = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images/" + fileName);

            FileStream fsObj = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            ms.WriteTo(fsObj);

            fsObj.Close();

            ms.Close();

            return fileHandle;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           return "";
        }

    }
```

**Update 2** (for timeout issues)

- NSURLRequest and NSMutableURLRequest default timeout period is 60
  seconds depending upon the Internet connectivity,Internet Traffic
  congestiion at webserver,ImageCreating time and all it may not be
  enough.so you can set the value higher than that using the following
  syntax `[urlReqObj setTimeoutInterval:180];` the timeout interval is
  in seconds only.
- Increase the ConnectionTimeout in IIS default value is 120 seconds sometimes if so many requests queue in the request will fail.Increasing the ConnectionTimeOut will help.(This timeout is also for idle time of a connection).To set it in IIS Advanced Settings 
  Click on your `service in IIS Manager -> Advanced Settings -> Connection Limits` and there you can set the timeout or you could simple override the connection timeout in `web.config`.
- Turn on `Keep-alive in IIS` so that same connection is reused thus increasing the effeceincy of IIS.
  Click on your `service in IIS Manager -> Advanced Settings -> Connection Limits -> Enable HTTP Keep-Alives`
- If you plan to store the binary of image in DB.you can increase the DB `connectiontimeout` in `connectionstring` or you can increase the `sqlcommandtimeout`

Hope this helps.
Feel free to ask if you have any doubts

Comment: Hiii @Duraiamuthan.H. Thanks for your response. But I've already tried the above method and nothing happens. Can you see my server side code? May be its wrong. Can you check that once? I've posted that too. Its expecting a byte array. Not a base64 encoded string. Thank you

Comment: @sreekanthk - Welcome ! I have updated my answer ! Feel free to ask if you encounter any problem.

Comment: Ok. I'm working on it. I'll let you know the result. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the request timed out issue. Can you help me on this issue?

Comment: Here is another answer which is related with uploading the image on server and size problem..http://stackoverflow.com/a/29198665/730807 it will be helpful to you on some other circumstances