# XMLReader Xcode Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, soap, xcode6

Firstly, as I see many others seem to announce when they ask these types of questions, I'm a beginner to Objective C. I've come from a strong PHP background, so I do understand most programming concepts, and have been learning Obj C on and off for the past 12 months.

One of my first projects to get my feet wet with iOS Objective C was to integrate with the Magento SOAP API. Probably not the easiest thing to begin with, but nonetheless it's a good challenge.

I'm currently trying to integrate XMLReader (https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader). But XCode keeps throwing me an error:
ARC Semantic Issue: No known class method for selector 'dictionaryForNSXMLParser:'

Which refers to the following code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:parser];
```

I found some advice from another question:
[How can you use AFNetworking or STHTTPRequest to make a request of a SOAP web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308227/how-can-you-use-afnetworking-2-0-to-make-a-request-of-a-soap-web-service)

I've reverted my code to mirror exactly the examples provided in the question, so I've been wracking my brain to work this error out, but to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated, and I apologise if this is something stupid which I have overlooked. I've tried scouring google for similar issues, but they all seem to be leading to class methods being called on an instance, etc.

Comment: XMLReader has no public class method called "dictionaryForNSXMLParser"

Comment: That's right. But from the other question thread which I also mentioned, it adds the public class method for 'dictionaryForNSXMLParser', as well as adding the method 'objectWithNSXMLParser'.

Comment: "Class method" requires a + ... instance method requires a -.  Have you mirrored that exactly?

Comment: Definitely mirrored it exactly. I originally typed all the methods in, but then copy/pasted it all, and even tried deleting the class files and starting over again. No luck.. I'm kinda stumped on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying that code myself just a minute ago.

You have to add in `XMLReader.h`:

```
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryForNSXMLParser:(NSXMLParser*)parser error:(NSError **)error;
```

Then in the `XMLReader.m` these two:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForNSXMLParser:(NSXMLParser *)xmlParser error:(NSError **)error
{
    XMLReader *reader = [[XMLReader alloc] initWithError:error];
    NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [reader objectWithNSXMLParser:xmlParser options:0];
    return rootDictionary;
}
- (NSDictionary *)objectWithNSXMLParser:(NSXMLParser *)xmlParser options:(XMLReaderOptions)options
{
    // Clear out any old data
    self.dictionaryStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    // Initialize the stack with a fresh dictionary
    [self.dictionaryStack addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];

    [xmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:(options & XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces)];
    [xmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:(options & XMLReaderOptionsReportNamespacePrefixes)];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:(options & XMLReaderOptionsResolveExternalEntities)];

    xmlParser.delegate = self;
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    // Return the stack's root dictionary on success
    if (success)
    {
        NSDictionary *resultDict = [self.dictionaryStack objectAtIndex:0];
        return resultDict;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

After that remember to import XMLReader.h and use the method. ***Notice*** that it has the error handling in it so if you copy pasted the code it's not same.

```
[XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:parser error:nil];
```

If it still doesn't work try cleaning the project with `CMD`+`SHIFT`+`K` and building it again.

Comment: Adding `error:nil` to the method did the trick! Thank you so much!