# how to turn AFNetworking GET request to soap web service request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

The project I'm working on have using AFHTTPRequestOperation to retrieve data from the web service using the down below method but now the company want to change this method and make it a soap request  can i modify the current code the project have more than 100 class and so advanced and I'm still beginner can any one help me 2 modify the code to use the soap request and accept the soap message and requests with a simple edit or something plz ,this is the code that exist :

```
  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*********?mobile=%@&email=%@",mobile,email];

    [self.operationManager GET:path parameters:nil success:^void(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^void(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError * error) {

}];
```

I have tried to follow the answer  on ([How can you use AFNetworking or STHTTPRequest to make a request of a SOAP web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308227/how-can-you-use-afnetworking-or-sthttprequest-to-make-a-request-of-a-soap-web-se)) but in the part where i call it in the other class that i need to use it in this error showed (No known class method for selector 'dictionaryForNSXMLParser:'). i found the problem i didn't call 
NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:parser error:nil]; 
but he did the same ,he  used 
 NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:parser];but while running the app it crashed in XMLReader.m class on this line 
        self.errorPointer = *error; 
    XMLReader *reader = [[XMLReader alloc] initWithError:error];
ther error is EC_Bad_Access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308227/how-can-you-use-afnetworking-or-sthttprequest-to-make-a-request-of-a-soap-web-se

Comment: ya i tried it but when i added the method he used in XMLReader this error comes up  when i call it in the other class (No known class method for selector 'dictionaryForNSXMLParser:').

Comment: i found the problem i didn't call NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:parser error:nil]; but he did the same ,he  used NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:parser]; why didn't it work for me?